# Is it possible to declare a self executing runnable?

Tags: java, constructor

Like so?

```
abstract public class BaseTask extends Runnable {
    public BaseTask(ParamA aParam) {
         // do something with aParam
         StaticExecutorService.submit(this);
    }
}

public class AbcTask extends BaseTask {
    public ABC(ParamA aParam, ParamB bParam) {
        super(aParam);
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {

    }
}
```

The class can then just be created and queued for execution by doing a

```
new AbcTask();
```

1. I'm not sure if this is ok because maybe it is still being constructed when `ExecutorService` decides to execute `AbcTask`?
2. If you don't recommend this for whatever reason, please state and elaborate.

Thanks

Comment: *"please state and elaborate"*  Please state and elaborate the goal you are trying to accomplish.  What program feature does this offer to the end user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example it will probably work **but** as the call to `super()` has to be the first in child classes of `BaseTask` this means that the constructor won't be able to perform any operation before the submission of the task.

From you sample, the second parameter cannot be used since the task will be submitted before you can assign it to an attribute.

If we consider the following code:

```
public class MyTask extends BaseTask {
    public ABC(ParamA aParam, String name) {
        super(aParam);
        this.name = name == null ? "Default Value" : name;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
         System.out.println("Name length: "+ name.length());
    }
}
```

Since `run()` can be called before the assignment of `this.name` the `System.out` line can end in `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 2):

This might work (at least, I'm not familiar enough with Java to see why it wouldn't), but I would not recommend it as it introduces too strong a coupling: `AbcTask` would be tied to `StaticExecutorService` and would be less reusable than it could easily be. This will also make the `AbcTask` harder to test and debug.

Also, you're "overloading" the meaning of object construction by folding submission to an executor into it. What if, later on, you decide you want to do something to `AbcTask` objects in between constructing them and submitting them?

Answer (score 1):

We should not use `this` until the constructor is completed.

An object is instantiated fully after completion of it's c'tor. so the object passed within `StaticExecutorService` might not be created fully and may not be usable.

I don't know if specification supports my above statement. but i feel so.

Hence, acc. to me it should be avoided.

Comment: Good point. So I guess it could happen that the object has not been fully instantiated which would wreck havoc?

Answer (score 1):

1. Its tightly coupled
2. In Effective Java, Joshua Bloch explained why it is not a good practice to invoke a protected/public method from a constructor. See 2nd edition, CH-4: Constructors must not invoke overridable methods, **directly** or **indirectly**.

   ```
   StaticExecutorService.submit(this);
   ```

   Above line will invoke the public method `run` from the constructor, and this is not expected.

---

Explanation from the book: Constructors must not invoke overridable methods, **directly** or **indirectly**

> If you violate this rule, program failure will result. The superclass constructor runs
>   before the subclass constructor, so the overriding method in the subclass will get
>   invoked before the subclass constructor has run. If the overriding method depends
>   on any initialization performed by the subclass constructor, the method will not
>   behave as expected.